# How can I dynamically render a PrimeFaces Output Panel based on a variable value exceeding a certain threshold?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to render a PrimeFaces Output Panel, when a variable (Percentage) is over 100. I would also like it to display with a Red outline and a light red filling on the Panel. Any ideas?

I have tried rendering it the standard way but I want to improve my functionality.